# Is it really impossible to read Http Headers in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript, http-headers, flash

You can set headers in ActionScript, but you can't read them unless you are using Flash Lite or AIR. This is really bizarre. Could this possibly be true? If this is true, can anyone think of a reason why?

Comment: security comes to mind, I havent used action script in ages but I believe the number of headers you can set are very limited as well for the same reason.

Comment: I can't see why reading headers would be a security issue. Setting would be more of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, Flash Player, when run in a web browser, uses the web browser for HTTP calls, rather than having its own HTTP implementation, and there are limitations in what the browser and the plugin communicates back and forth regarding headers and response codes and such.